# As well as + to + verb

Tags: grammar

I wrote the following sentence:

> He refused to get on another flight the following day, as well as to join the conference via Skype

However, I am not completely sure about the usage of "as well as" in this case. I have read other questions regarding this, as well as several online resources, and right now I feel as if this is not officially grammatically correct, but it still feels natural to me. It would be nice if a native speaker could give me some feedback.

Comment: It looks grammatical to me. *As well as* is a well-known conjunction and *to* preserves the stylistically parallel construction of the verbs.

Comment: I think ***as well as*** is a bit weird in this ***negating*** context, where it's much more idiomatic to  use ***or***. But this is really a question better addressed on 
[English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The point is that he refused to do both, and the negation is supposed to continue over both clauses. However, there is no overt negative in this sentence -- _refuse_ entails a negative complement clause, but that's not overt negation, and there's nothing after the third syllable of the sentence that reminds the reader of the negation. I would use _nor_ instead of _as well as_, to reinforce the negation of the first clause, as well as to mark the second clause as being part of a disjoined complement clause. Also, _nor_ is only one syllable, while _as well as_ is three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better to say:

> He refused either to get on another flight the following day, or to
>   join the conference via Skype.

Once you have said "either" your readers are expecting an "or". They recognize the structure of your sentence.

"As well as" is not usually followed by an infinitive verb.
Here are some examples:

> As well as killing the cat he stole the dog.
>
> He stole the cat as well as the dog.
>
> He annoyed me as well as you.
>
> Apples can be green as well as red.
>
> Shares can go down as well as up.